# mailcore にて Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials となってしまう

Tags: objective-c, gmail

度々の質問失礼します。
iosアプリを使ったメーラーを作ろうと思います。
ライブラリにmailcoreを使用し、サンプルコードを動かそうとしたところ、
以下のエラーメッセージがでて動かす事ができませんでした。
gmailにimapでつなぎに行っています。

解決方法をご存知の方がいましたらご教授いただけないでしょうか。

`2015-11-24 16:36:45.149 mails[3142:95579] Error downloading message headers:Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials.}

2015-11-24 16:36:45.150 mails[3142:95579] The post man delivereth:(null)`